# C# Beginner File Reading

Tags: c#, io, filestream

Okay I searched for an answer to this but couldn't find it.

here's the code:

```
     FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        byte[] fileText = new byte[fs.Length];

        int bytesRead = fs.Read(fileText, 0, fileText.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileText, 0, bytesRead));
```

Let me get this straight,

1. We declare a filestream
2. We Declare a byte array.. and set its CAPACITY to fs.Length
3. ???? Why does fs.Read() return an INTEGER ???
4. ??? How does this line display the text from the .txt file to the console? we passed in the byte[] in the getstring() method, but isnt that byte[] empty? we only set its capacity to fs.length? where did the reading happen and how?

TIA

Comment: What is your goal here? You have a text file, then what you want to do with it?

Comment: 3) Read() returns the actual number of bytes that were read because it may be less than the number of bytes requested.  4) The Read method() in your example put the data into the array filetext so filetext is not empty after the read is executed.

Comment: okay. so it filled the byte[] with the ASCII codes of all the characters?

Comment: The file just has "Hello World!" written in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to read a text file and display all it's lines in console

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines("YourFilePath"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

In your method

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("YourFilePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Opens the file for reading into stream fs.

```
byte[] fileText = new byte[fs.Length];
```

Gets the number of bytes in the file content, and creates a byte array of that size

```
int bytesRead = fs.Read(fileText, 0, fileText.Length);
```

Reads the byte content, from 0 to end of content (we have length from last statement), i.e. the complete contents into the array you created. So, now your byte array fileText has all the byte contents from the file.

It returns the number of bytes read in this operation, if you need that for some reason. This can be <= the number of bytes you wanted to read (less if less bytes were available in the file content). In your case, it will be same as fileText.Length since you already calculated that.

```
System.Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileText, 0, bytesRead));
```

Converts the byte array into ASCII encoded text and writes to console.

Comment: Thankyou, but i need to know THIS method and understand it :D

Answer (score 1):

[`FileStream.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of bytes actually read. It could be that you ask for 4096 bytes, but get 0, or 1, or 1000. This is what the docs say:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This might be less than the number of bytes requested if that number of bytes are not currently available, or zero if the end of the stream is reached.

If you are reading text, you can use one of the helpful `File` methods: [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx), [`File.ReadAllLines`,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`File.OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) which gives you a `StreamReader` object where you can read line-by-line.

If you need to read the bytes (this is a much lower-level usage, and really you should be able to use a `StreamReader`), then you don't want to create a buffer the length of the stream, since this could crash your program with an `OutOfMemoryException`. Instead, make the buffer something like 4096 bytes, then call `FileStream.Read` in a loop, until it returns 0. Note, however, that you are not reading text lines here, and a line break may come in the middle of the buffer. Here's an example:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("c:\\file.txt"))
{
    var buffer = new Byte[4096];
    var offset = 0;
    var read = 0;
    while ((read = fileStream.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read);
        Console.Write(s);
        offset += read;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read method returns the number of bytes that were read into the buffer paramters. You passed in an array that will be filled with the data when the Read method is actually called. You have passed in the number of bytes that you want to read as well.
Read the msdn documentation for more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

3) has been answered here already.

As for 4): the `Read` method actually also fills the buffer with bytes and returns the number of bytes it filled into the buffer.

Passing the buffer and the number of bytes read to `Encoding. GetString()` interprets the bytes from the file as character codes for the given encoding, in your case ASCII, and creates an string from the byte array based on the encoding.

Comment: what exactly is the byte[] filled with, the ASCII codes for the individual characters in the .txt file?

Comment: To be precise one has to say "with the bytes the file contains" . The interpretation of the bytes is up to you. A file (and thus a file stream) is actually just a sequence of bytes. To interpret them as text, you have to know the encoding. For example, UTF16 encoding requires two bytes power character. If you *know* you are reading a text file, there are specialized method for easily reading those. Some of them have been mentioned in other answers.